How deep should I check references of a papers I am going to cite?
I am a new researcher who just started writing scientific papers and am concerned about checking the papers I am planning to cite. When citing a specific paper, I always try to read most of the cited paper (at least the described methodology, results, and conclusions) and I generally put the trust into the authors (and peer review process) of cited papers since for most of the scientific papers data is either private or it would take too much time to repeat the experiments by myself. Additionally, I always try to check the paper I am about to cite by searching for it in Retraction Watch db, PubPeer, and problematic paper screener. However, this check will still not guarantee me that my papers in the future will not be flagged as problematic even if my methodology and experiments are correct.
For example, let's say I wrote paper A which cites paper B which cites paper C (in a literature overview section). A few years later paper, C is flagged as problematic (or even retracted) which also makes paper B problematic and indirectly my paper also. How should I deal with this kind of situation? It is obviously insane to check all references for a specific paper in depth. I am not sure today that I can trust peer review, citations, and all available information in order to avoid such things.

Would paper C being wrong affect your conclusions?

No. Paper C was cited by paper B in an literature overview section.

What field are you in? This amount of worry about papers (putting each one into multiple retraction databases?) is foreign to me.

"A few years later paper, C is flagged as problematic (or even retracted) which also makes paper B problematic" Why does the retraction of a paper cited in a literature overview make B problematic? There is absolutely no rule saying that you mustn't cite papers containing a reference to a retracted paper.

My question was inspired by a recent retractions of a lot of papers from the guest edited special issues from the journal Neural computing and applications by Springer. Reason for retractions were mostly irrelevant references and peer review manipulations. However, since these special issues were from few years ago, some of those retracted articles were cited several times by other authors. My question was mainly aimed to should I avoid those papers that cited those retracted papers. Most of them actually cited them in introduction section without further references in the following sections

@mt29 The situation you have just described is very different from what your question asked. I don't suggest you edit, you've already received an answer.

Re "I generally put the trust into the authors (and peer review process) of cited papers" I am a CS guy. When I try to implement what I read about in papers (mostly CS and math), about 50% of the time things do not work as advertised: Important preconditions for proper operation have been omitted, error bounds and efficiency claims are not stated correctly, etc. One's experience may differ based on field, but in general an attitude of "trust, but verify" seems advisable.

This is primarily from a math and CS perspective. It probably also applies to fields that primarily use statistical methods to establish evidence for the results.
Ideally, you want to read backwards until two things occur.
First, and most important, you want to assure yourself (at least minimally) that what you are reading is correct and the proofs (evidence) backs up the conclusions.
Second, though perhaps more difficult, is you want to gain insight into the class of problems that the papers explore. You may already have this insight, of course.
I say "ideally", because it is often difficult and time consuming to do this, so you may need to compromise a bit, though it is dangerous to do so.
The correctness in some fields is a bit easier since you can probably depend on the skills of reviewers for reputable journals to have vetted the results. This sometimes fails, of course.
Insight is harder, but you need that to advance in these fields and maybe others as well. And insight will help you recognize the occasional paper with incorrect results that, nevertheless, passed peer review.

If possible, for every paper you cite you should always try

Get the actual paper and store it for future reference. It is super embarrassing to answer to a reader of your paper, that you cannot hand over a copy of a reference, because you never obtained a copy yourself.
Check the paper states the claimed statement. If a claim is only backed by another citation, consider citing this paper, too, including all the checks you did for the first paper.
Skim through other papers citing your paper. Sometimes there are rebuttals you can identify by their titles. Be extra careful, if nobody else is citing the paper.


Might the first point depend on the copyright licence terms?

@AndrewMorton - if you can’t read the paper, don’t cite the paper.

@JonCuster I think Andrew means the "hand over a copy" part of my answer. He is right, but usually in personal communication this is not that much an issue. E.g., US law has a fair use clause. Usually this is only a problem for old or obscure publications, that have no financial interest (PhD thesis, internal technical report, presentation on a professors big birthday celebration).
